# the_author function is displaying wrong name and url

Tags: author, author-template

There is a problem by using the_author();
in file author.php I use this code to display author name heading

```
<h1 class="page-title"><a>آخرین اخبار</a> <a href="<?php the_author_url(); ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_author(); ?></a></h1>
```

but the title and url are wrong and belong to another author!
Notice : this code is outside of loop

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but I found the answer very quickly myself and I attempted to delete this original question, but I think maybe somebody else may need this answer.

This is right code to solve this issue:

```
<h1 class="page-title">  <?php echo '<a href="'.get_author_posts_url(get_userdata($posts[0]->post_author)->data->ID).'">'.get_userdata($posts[0]->post_author)->data->display_name.'</a>'; ?></h1>
```

Comment: the `post_author` is already the ID, so you can simplify it to `get_author_posts_url( $posts[0]->post_author )`, however, this answer implies you're using `get_posts` or a custom `WP_Query` to replace or change the posts shown on your author archives, and that the loop you spoke of is not a main loop but a secondary loop, which would go a long way to explaining your problem. If you added more information to your question to confirm this and share the loop it might be possible to make `the_author` and `the_author_url` work as you expected _and_ speed up that page